# Unknown schematic symbol

Tags: symbol

Does anyone know what the "Z" lying down symbol is that is in parallel with the normally closed relay contact CRB? I have searched several electrical symbol sites but no luck. The circuit is controlling 24 Vdc power for a motor brake. There is a back EMF arc when this contact opens so the symbol could represent a snubber which in this case may have failed. It will be this weekend before I can physically go in and look for this device. One other bit of info, this machine was built in Japan about 30 years ago.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that is a metal oxide varistor (MOV) or another TVS (Transient Voltage Supressor). Look at [this](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/CctSymbols/Circuit_Symbols.html) symbol table.
The MOV symbol is near the middle of the table, with an image.

[image]

Comment: From that list, it looks more like their VDR symbol

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes. Sorry, is a Metal Oxide Varistor!

Comment: @DavidE. If this is the correct answer, please mark it for future references.

Comment: @Martin Petrei. I do not know how to do that. Is that an action that I can perform in this forum? I will try to search that.